# Multiple Java installation pointing to one cacert file in a share path

Tags: java, linux, window

I have many applications on different servers and each application uses many versions of Java.  Now whenever we renew SSL certificate we have to copy imported cacerts file to all the Java on all the applications (around 50 locations in 20 servers).  So is there a way I can have one cacerts file (in shared path) and all java installations pointing to the one cacerts file.  This way I need to have the cacerts file in only one location everytime when there is a SSL certificate renewal.

P.S :  I have Java installed on windows as well as Linux

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it might be possible to have all your machines running JVMs point to a shared network drive. And that means that you create a single point of failure. When that shared drive goes belly up, so could *all* your JVMs. Typically, that is *bad* for your business.

The real answer in 2018: configuration should be *code*.

Meaning: your whole setup is created out of some sort of *instructions* that can be applied/executed automatically using tools. Like [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/), or [chef/puppet](https://www.chef.io/puppet/).

The answer is not to introduce a single point of failure, but to use state of the art tooling to get to a point where "releasing is simple", and not "releasing means drama".

You see, that shared file solution has many other problems, such as: it means that you update the config for all your JVMs at the same point. Does that mean you have to tear down all running instances, together?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion.  yes, I accept this introduces single point of failure.  But my management want to go ahead with this but I do stress the single point of failure.  We might not be in a position to introduce configuration as code.  Given all these, do you have any idea on my question?